# use toString() in overload construct ? how

Tags: java, overloading, tostring

### i have several Constructor in the class

```
public class Date {
       ...
       public Date(first case)
       ...
       public Date(second case)
       ...
       public Date(third case)
       ...
       public String toString(){
       ...}
```

How to write the code in toSTring() ????

Can any one explain to me

Comment: What's the problem? What do you want to return in that `toString()`?

Comment: your question was not clear.can you explain more about your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your `toString` returns is not decided by how many `constructor` you have in your class. They are used to `return` a `String` representation that you want to be printed when you print the instances of your class. You can return any field or concatenation of some fields from it.

So, if you have a `Person` class with some `4-5 fields` including `id` and `name` and you want to print the `id` and `name` of the person separated by a colon, when you print the instanse, your `toString()` would look like:-

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.id + " : " + this.name;
}
```

So, if you have an instance of `Person` class with `id = 5`, `name = rohit`, `age = 23` and some `email id`, then when you display that instance: -

```
Person person = new Person(5, "rohit", "rohit@gmail.com", 23);
System.out.println(person);

Person person2 = new Person(6);  // Don't have `name` set
System.out.println(person2);
```

The above statement will print: -

```
5 : rohit
6 :
```

as output.

But you can of course put a condition in your `toString` to check whether a field is empty or not, and you can return a message accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but if i have another Constructor


Person(id,email,age) without e-mail

and i want to show both

Comment: @Huei That doesn't matter.. If you don't have email, it will simply return an `empty` string for that..

Comment: @Huei Or you can check it before returning, and return `any value` when it is not set.

Comment: That's why 
i want to present both in different
but i only can write toString() in once

Comment: @Huei. Yes you can do it as I said. You can put a condition, and for each of them, return a different String, as per your choice.. As I said, number of constructors, does not affect what your toString looks like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, try to figure out

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() {
    return case1 != null ? case1 : case2 != null ? case2 : case3 != null ? case3 : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java toString can be very useful for representing objects in text form.  You should always overwrite toString() in order to have accessibility to proper debugging / logging.  Here's a sample of a class that might make a good example.

```
public class Person {
    private final String _name;
    private final Integer _age;
    private final Date _birthday;

    public Person(String name, Integer age, Date birthday) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._birthday = new Date(birthday.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [_name=" + _name + ", _age=" + _age + ", _birthday="
                + _birthday + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toString method should represent the "state" of your object, so isn't related with constructors but with your class attributes.